# Updating / deleting arbitrary rows in column without primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am building a tool that will display all the tables in a given PostgreSQL database (client's legacy app), then the user would dig in and can see all the data in given table. It is essentially a database viewer.

Next step will be to allow user to update each row, in a similar manner to how one updates data in Airtable.

While for most columns I will have the primary keys so I can use to build appropriate `Update ... where ID=?` statements, I realized that may not be the case always. For some join tables, for example, I do not have the ID or any other primary key.

I still would like to have the functionality where the user looks at the grid of data displayed from such columns, selects a row with click of mouse and provides new values.

PostgreSQL *used to* use OIDs to uniquelly identify rows for such cases, but this is no longer the case even for the legacy database I am dealing with.

The only solution I can think of is using the offset/sort order to figure out which row is to be updated, but this leads to race conditions if sort changes in the meantime or the user deletes/adds some rows.

Any ideas how I can update such "anonymous" rows?

Comment: I figured there is a special column called `ctid` that might be of a help in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Each table in Postgres has a system column `ctid` which unambiguously identifies a row. Example:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id int, str text);
insert into my_table values
(1, 'one'),
(1, 'two'),
(2, 'one');

select ctid, *
from my_table;

 ctid  | id | str 
-------+----+-----
 (0,1) |  1 | one
 (0,2) |  1 | two
 (0,3) |  2 | one
(3 rows)
```

You can use the column in `delete` or `update`:

```
delete from my_table
where ctid = '(0,2)'
returning *

 id | str 
----+-----
  1 | two
(1 row)

DELETE 1
```

Note however, that there is no guarantee that a row has always the same `ctid`, per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

> ctid
>
> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.